# Imputation and Distributions

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

Suppose you impute a variable using a normal distribution with mean 10 and sd 5. Is it better to draw 1000 random samples from this normal distribution, take the average, and then use this to impute this missing value? Or can I just take one draw from this distribution and use this as the value to impute the missing data?

Comment: Why are you simulating for imputation? There's a particular reason you might want to... and that would preclude taking an average. However, perhaps more importantly, why are you doing using a N(10,5) in particular?

Comment: @Glen_b: Because I don't want to just use the everage to impute the data.

Comment: Right ... and why not? Why would you like to avoid the average? And why is the simulation size of 1000 important, rather than 10000 say? You answers here will reveal whether averaging makes any sense at all.

Comment: @Glen_b: The higher the simulation size, you would get a "better" estimate of the missing data value? I want to avoid the average because that would bias the relationship between the predictor variables. That is why I am doing something similar to multiple imputation.

Comment: @Glen_b: I did. I want to avoid using the average because it will bias the relationship between the predictor variables. And the simulation size of 1000 was just used as an example.

Comment: What happens if you take the sample mean of larger and larger samples, and use those to impute instead?

Comment: @Glen_b: That could work. So for each missing value, draw from a distribution with larger and larger samples?

Comment: I'm NOT telling you to do this, I am trying to get you to understand why it does what you said you didn't want to do. Consider what happens to $25/\sqrt{n}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Glen_b: The sample mean would converge to the true mean.

Comment: Right. And didn't you start by saying that you didn't want that?

Comment: So why average at all? You were simulating from the original distribution for a reason.

Comment: @Glen_b: Yes. that is why I am not using the sample mean to impute. I am drawing from a distribution to impute.

Comment: Sigh. When you draw a simulation sample from a normal (10,25) distribution, and average **THAT** sample, as that simulation sample size increases you eventually just get "10" all the time, with essentially no error. Does that make sense, to just use 10?

Comment: @Glen_b: For each of the ages, I am drawing from one nimber from a N(10,25) distribution. I am not drawing all of them at the same time.

Comment: Please reread your question above, where it says: '*Is it better to draw 1000 random samples from this normal distribution*, ***take the average***'... -- that's what I am discussing.

Comment: @Glen_b: ok. But if I just use single draws then that would be okay? For example, if I draw an 8.5 then use that for one missing value. If I draw a 10.5 then use this for the second missing value, etc.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'okay'. It sounds like it will do what you were originally attempting to do, but I don't know how you arrived at the decision to do what you're attempting to do. I'm working on no information on that point, so it's hard to judge its okayness.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  What distribution do you want the imputation to reflect? $$\mathrm{N}(10, 25)$$ or $$\mathrm{N}(10,\frac{25}{\sqrt{1000}})?$$

Your second task could be accomplished in $0.1\%$ of the time by implementing my second suggestion.

I want to emphasize that I am **not** endorsing *either* of these approaches for your intended application (imputing missing values).  My point is that sampling $n$ i.i.d $\mathrm{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and computing $\bar{X}_n$ is exactly equivalent (and indistinguishable) from drawing a single value from $\mathrm{N}(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$, provided you discard the observations in the first case.